# custom query to get posts

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, query

I want to create custom links like

`mydomain.com/custom_page/cat=ABC&tag=XYZ`

So that when a user clicks on the link s/he can see all posts in the category 'ABC' having tag 'XYZ'

For this I've created a custom template with the following code

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: MyCustomTemplate
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
global $wp_query;
get_query_var( 'cat' );
get_query_var( 'tag' );
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I don't know how to query for the posts in the category 'ABC' with the tag 'XYZ'

I checked http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Passing_variables_to_query_posts

but the examples shown there use 'static' values. I need to query using dynamic values: which are passed via the URL.

Also, I'm using a plugin 'Advanced Custom Fields' and have added a field 'priority' with the defult value 'Z'. I intend to assign one alphabet to each post in the priority field, so that results on the page are served sorted according to "priority" : Posts with the priority 'A' on the top, followed by posts with priority 'B' and so on..

**In Short**:

I want to get category and tag parameters from links like:

`mydomain.com/custom_page/cat=some_category&tag=some_tag`

Then Fetch posts
in the category 'some_category' AND having tag 'some_tag' AND sorted according to custom field : 'priority'

Comment: Can you just make your question more clear with entering only required information in the question?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous question. I have added a summary in the end of the post. If that doesn't help, please mention what clarifications you need.

Comment: FYI, WordPress already possesses the ability to filter post archives on multiple taxonomies without having to run custom queries. see [this post](http://thereforei.am/2011/10/28/advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-pretty-urls/).

Answer (score 1):

**Clarification of your question:**
You want to show Posts of a certain category named "ABC" AND also you want to filter the posts with the tag named "XYZ".

**Answer:**
If this is the scenario, have you tried: [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)?

```
<?php    
// The Query

$args = array('post_type' => 'post',
              'category_name' => 'ABC',
              'tag' => 'XYZ',
              'meta_key' => 'priority',
              'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
             );

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Something like this may solve your problem.

> **NOTE:** I din't test this one, try yourself with it. If you face any problem, please comment here, or if you find any solution, don't forget to share that with me here.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Let me test it. How can I have variable in the array? I mean instead of `'category_name' => 'ABC'` I want `'category_name' => $some_category`

I've added a summary of the question at the end of my post.

Comment: Visit the codex page for WP_Query() - I linked earlier, there you will find solution: [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters).

Comment: Works! Thank you. Though instead of using 'A', 'B' etc for priority, now I'm using numbers as it makes more sense. The posts with highest 'priority' is displayed on top.
Also, on the category page, WP lists all the post of a particular category. Can you suggest how can I make it to display on the basis of priority?
So that when someone visits mysite.com/category/ABC posts are displayed according to the priority..

PS: there's a typo. '$' is missing in : `new WP_Query(args);`
I tried to crrect it, but couldn't. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can get variables from $_REQUEST, but you must first reset permalinks to default format and make sure this is correct variable names. In your case it's $_REQUEST['cat'] and $_REQUEST['tag'], so the dynamic query will be

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'category_name' => sanitize_title_for_query( $_REQUEST['cat'] ),
  'tag' => sanitize_title_for_query( $_REQUEST['tag'] ),
  'meta_key' => 'priority',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not preparing your query correctly. First of all the data should be fetched associatively and you are displaying it differently. for code practice its bad.|

regarding your actual error. your query seems good but once again do this associatively. so your query should look like $post_tag => 'ABC'. then prepare, sanitize your query and push it into your database.

Comment: If you want to get an upvote put some effort into taking the OPs original code, making the changes/fixes, and then explain them.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).